# Windows APIs in .NET 5 - Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll is 25MB?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-5

I'm following the [Calling Windows APIs in .NET5](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2020/09/03/calling-windows-apis-in-net5/) guide to call the Notification APIs in my WPF app. However now it's put a 25MB `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll` in my output directory. This would increase my app's download size by 50% just for a small feature. Is there a way to shave this down to just the APIs I need?

Comment: [App Trimming in .NET 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/app-trimming-in-net-5/). Use data compression like 7zip to create the download package.

Comment: Already compressing via the installer. Does app trimming work on WinRT projection DLLs?

Comment: Did a publish with Trim Unused Assemblies enabled but it did not change the size of `Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll`.

Comment: my 2mb app now has a 25MB dll, did anyone find a solution to this? unfortunately I don't know which feature change even added this sdk, any idea how to trace it down?

Comment: @shoaib30: This happens if in your .csproj file the target framework has a `-windows{someVersion}` suffix. Remove the suffix and the SDK reference is gone. If anything from the SDK is used within your project you'll get some compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can design an update package or a set of update packages to draw up an optimized patch strategy to *defer* this fat assembly download by arranging it in a separate dependency package. What is more the user would not even download it in the event your new feature had not been selected during installation. [MSIX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-package-updates) shall be eligible to set up this kind of package ecosystem.